# In a foreach (string word in words) how can I go to next word if (if->true) C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string

The idea is that he inputs a text file, and a word number. The software will write in a new file that text but with number of words (that he inputed) per line, and few other details.

The idea is this, I made him a blacklist. The blacklist is loaded into a richbox from a file, and saved while closing application.

The thing is that I have everything set up (a function that checks if the word is in blackbox).

The software looks like this:

```
foreach (string word in words)
{
     int blacklist = 0;

     if (FindMyText(word))
     {
           blacklist = 1;
           MessageBox.Show("Current word: " + word + " is blacklisted!");
     }
     else
           MessageBox.Show("Word: " + word);               

     // the code here ... for writing in file and all that

     }
```

The function FindMyText(word) tells me if the word is in blacklist or not.

If that function returns true, I want to step to the next word, but really don't know how to do this.

If you have some ideas, would really help me out.

Thanks you guys.

Comment: foreach will iterate over all words. What is not working? Can you provide example?

Comment: You could store each word you find in another list which you can then summarize at the end of the function; break your code down into two steps; 1) Finding "blacklisted" words and collecting them then 2) do something with that collection. If that's what you want to do, can provide an example.

Comment: Is `continue` what you're looking for?  It would skip everything else in the block and go to the next word....

Comment: `break` would exit the whole loop, whereas [`continue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664757%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) goes to the the next iteration ignoring the rest of the loop.

Comment: @phg: Yeah, that's what I meant.  I fixed it.

Comment: any reason for using an int for blacklist when it's either 0 or 1 (at least in the snippet)

Comment: well, I was thinking in other ways, to skip the word. I added continue and removed the integer. Thanks!

Comment: @icebox19 You may want to consider just collecting the words and then summarizing at the end. Repeated MessageBox appearances can be frustrating for a user!

Answer (score 1):

in a foreach loop or any other loop you can use the `continue` to skip to the next iteration so in your case you could do

```
foreach (string word in words)
{
  var blacklist = 0;
  if (FindMyText(word))
  {
    blacklist = 1;
    MessageBox.Show("Current word: " + word + " is blacklisted!");
    continue;
  } else {
     //...
  }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, thanks guys, I was looking for continue; lol. I tried break, but ye, it was comming outta loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could just add the "continue" keywork to skip to the next element in the foreach iteration.

```
foreach (string word in words)
{
    int blacklist = 0;
    if (FindMyText(word))
    {
        blacklist = 1;
        MessageBox.Show("Current word: " + word + " is blacklisted!");
        // skip to the next element
        continue;
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Word: " + word);
    // the code here ... for writing in file and all that

}
```

or you could just split the foreach body :

```
foreach (string word in words)
{
    int blacklist = 0;
    if (FindMyText(word))
    {
        blacklist = 1;
        MessageBox.Show("Current word: " + word + " is blacklisted!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Word: " + word);
        // the code here ... for writing in file and all that
    }
}
```

It all depends on how long the "else" part is. If it is really long, it is more readable to use continue, to put the emphasis on the skipping part.

Comment: +1 for correct answer. Suggestion: You can lose the else if you have the continue. I think a big point in continue and break is to reduce indenting for easier reading.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the logic, just add `continue`:

The continue statement passes control to the next iteration of the enclosing iteration statement in which it appears. It takes the following form:

```
if (FindMyText(word))
{
  blacklist = 1;
  MessageBox.Show("Current word: " + word + " is blacklisted!");
  continue;
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("Word: " + word);
  AddWordToFile(word); // not black listed;
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand but I think what you want is the "continue" keyword.

Once an iteration of the loop is complete it will start again until it runs out of iterations.

So in your IF/ Else statement, you want to force the loop to go onto the next word, you type continue;. This will ignore all of the preceding code in the loop and jump to the next iteration.

Does that make sense?